# How do you remove a leading newline in output to browser in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, browser, newline

I have been having issues with a newline appearing in my browser output with Codeigniter. What happens is I am outputting JSON data, but there is a newline character before any of the JSON data, and it is messing stuff up.

Comment: Is the newline in the data string or somewhere else? Is the issue limited to this instance, or happens on *all* your output. Feel free to show your code, like how you are sending output to the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely you have some whitespace at the end of one of your PHP files.  It is a pretty common problem if you use the closing tag `?>`.

You'll want to search your code files and look for a `?>` with a newline character after it.  Anything after a closing tag gets output to the browser.

As a habit, I don't use closing tags in code files for this reason, as they are not required by the PHP interpreter.  Some coding standards recommend this as well.  I only use them in template files where there is additional output between/after the PHP code.

Comment: If anyone runs into this, it may be a frustrating issue. I went into my Codeigniter controller that contained the function I was using, and noticed that I had a newline in my controller, above the starting php tag:  
  
    *blank line was here*  
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  
  
So, make sure you have no newlines before or after your php tags (as @zombat has pointed out).