# Removing tabs from Codeigniter pages at the begining of document

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am getting 8 lines inserted at the beginning of each page in codeigniter framework, is it something with the framework and how do i remove these lines. I have tried to use hooks to minify html but i cant seem to remove the new lines inserted.

Comment: What are the "lines"? We need more information.

Comment: @Craig They are tabs /n inserted in the pages. I.e we have 8 tabs then the html begins at line number 9..

Comment: Can you add your controller code and image of view as well

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from [How do you remove a leading newline in output to browser in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607487/how-do-you-remove-a-leading-newline-in-output-to-browser-in-codeigniter). The issue was new lines after php closing tag "?>" in one of my modules.

Comment: It is good to follow [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html?highlight=closing%20tag#php-closing-tag).